# Oracle SQL - Substring issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an field `pattern` and value in that field is `INDI/17-18/6767/KER/787` .I want to get 6767 from this string

I used the query

```
select substr(pattern,12,15) from pattern_table
```

But the output I got is `6767/KER/787` instead of `6767`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

You have to give the `length` as the 3rd value, not the `position`.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(pattern,12,4) FROM pattern_table
```

Answer (score 0):

For a generic result to get the 3rd value separated by a delimiter, you may use `REGEXP_SUBSTR`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e971b/9)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT pattern,REGEXP_SUBSTR(pattern, '[^/]+', 1, 3) id
FROM pattern_table
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e971b/9/0)**:

```
|                  PATTERN |    ID |
|--------------------------|-------|
|  INDI/17-18/6767/KER/787 |  6767 |
| INDI/17-18-19/67/KER/787 |    67 |
| INDI/16-18/67890/KAR/986 | 67890 |
```

Answer (score 0):

even this will also work:

```
SELECT substr('INDI/17-18/6767/KER/787',instr('INDI/17- 
18/6767/KER/787','/',1,2)+1,4) FROM dual;
```